# Cam lock & dowel alternatives

Tags: repair, screws, wooden-furniture, carpentry, self-assembly-furniture

I have a chest of small chest of drawers held together by metal cam lock & dowel pegs. The cam lock & dowel regularly come loose. I am looking for suggestions for alternatives?

- the cam lock diameters are 12mm and they are 10mm deep
- the dowels are 30 mm long and 5mm diameter

One idea is to use wooden dowels with glue but I like the idea of being able to dismantle so am looking for suggestions for alternatives.

Comment: Are the current dowels deformed where the camlocks clamp down? If so, consider replacements.   Another thing to try is to wrap the camlocks in a layer of tape so they are a more snug fit in their hole.

Comment: I was going to suggest gluing and screwing it together until I read you wanted the option to be able to take it apart. So you could just drill pilot holes and screw it together for strength and this would give you the ability to take the screws out when you wanted to take it apart.

Comment: If it's made of particle board, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_board, it may be difficult to replace the fasteners because of particle board's brittleness and tendency to split. In that case, you could just add a *small* dab of glue or "liquid nails" at each to increase adhesion and reduce tendency to loosen.